# Navigation from Appdelegate to tab view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How to navigate from Appdelegate to another view(a tabview).
I have tried this

```
  MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:mvc] autorelease];
   self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

It navigates to MyViewController, but tab bar is hidden,also back button is not working(popView) in that view

**I am navigating to a view which is not a tabviewcontroller(only tab bar is hidden)**

Comment: You are just creating a normal `rootviewcontroller` , So you can't POP out. Here you are not creating any `Tabbar` so how it will come ? Check My Answer.

Comment: You are added a simple controller not a tabbarcontroller. for tabbarcontroller you have push tabbarconrtoller not a controller

Comment: Can you Explain What you need Actually ?? What does it mean   " I am navigating to a view which is not a tabviewcontroller(only tab bar is hidden) "

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota -- Let say,i have 5 tabviews, and also many other subviews.Even if i navigate to any of that sub view,Tabbar will be there.

Now I want to navigate to one of that subview from appdelegate,at that time Tabbar is hidden,
And also there is a back button in that view(using [self.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];),It is also not working

Comment: First Create A NormalViewController as Root wiewController. Then from there Navigate to tabbar Controller (Use my code). Use Tabbar.selectedViewController method to push particular tabbar. Then you can POP out Easily. Also you can Create Custom delegate in your Appdelegate which will reduce your burden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Creating Tabbar

```
tabBar_Controller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *localControllersArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];


firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
nav.tabBarItem.title = @"item1";
nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[localControllersArray addObject:nav];
[self setNav:nil];

secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
nav.tabBarItem.title = @"item2";
[localControllersArray addObject:nav];
[self setNav:nil];

tabBar_Controller.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
tabBar_Controller.delegate = self;
tabBar_Controller.selectedIndex = 0;

 self.window.rootViewController = tabBar_Controller;
```

You can try  This also, in your `Appdelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[SPHFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SPHFirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SPHSecondViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"SPHSecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: check my edited answer and And let me know it helps or not ? Also Post some codes for tab-bar what you have written ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

{

    UINavigationController *navigation;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
```

//Main file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

@synthesize viewController = _viewController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

   self.window.rootViewController = navigation;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;

}
```